# Python Index Conflict

Tags: python, list, indexing

[image]

This is a picture from an open course. Inside this pic, `s='Arthur'`, `s[5:2:-2] == 'ut'`. It makes sense, since `[:2]` is "Ar" and `[3:]` is "hur", but this is somehow wrong in reality. I typed `s[5:2:-2]` and the output was "rh". I also get it because index 5 is 'r', but since `:2` starts at 'r', reverse 5 should start at 'u'. It's really confusing and this is a really good course from the top university. Where is it going wrong?

Comment: I think you are correct and the slide is wrong - `s[4:1:-2]` give the `'ut'` shown.

Comment: yeah i know, i'm asking about the logic here, since [:2] is 'Ar', 'rh' doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the author did make a boo-boo. It's common advice to think of string indices as locations *between* letters, not the letters themselves, so index 5 is between `u` and `r`. But this mental aid is only appropriate for positive steps. It's easier to see with a negative step of 1: If you write `s[5:4:-1]`, you will extract the letter to the *right* of index `5`, i.e. `r`. Similarly, `s[1:0:-1]` will get you the *second* letter: `r`.

This means that `s[5:4:-1]` picks out `s[5]`, i.e. it is the same string position as `s[5:6:1]`, not `s[4:5:1]` as the creator of that image clearly assumed. In other words, the reality is that index `5` really picks out a character, not an inter-character position. Slices with negative step start *at* the character at index `5`, and move backwards in steps. And slices really stop *before* the character at the second index of the slice; pretending that indexes are between characters is a nice intuitive aid, but as you've discovered it's only appropriate when the slice step is positive.

Comment: then can you explain why [:2] outputs "Ar", in the same logic of yours [:2] should print out 'Art'

Comment: That's not really what my explanation predicts. Slices just stop before the second index. The "between positions" business is a rationalization.

Comment: I'd cut the author some slack, I readily admit I got unsure a couple of times while writing this answer. Negative indices are just not that widely used by most of us, so it's easy to get carried away by the "between characters" metaphor. Good for you to spot it, though!

Comment: On the other hand you should let the author know about the mistake so they can fix it.

Comment: thanks, it makes perfect sense now, the author probably already knows it, because that class was not provided with videos only slides.